# Remove Cortana from start menu

Tags: windows-10, cortana, windows-10-v1803

I've been trying to remove the Cortana icon from the start menu for a while now but haven't been successful yet.
How do you guys do it?

This is the [current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qWGM.png)

All I want to do is remove/hide the Cortana icon, not remove its search functionality.

I already tried renaming the Cortana folder in `%SystemRoot%\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy`

This only broke the search functionality but didn't remove the icon from the start menu.

I also read about moving the `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\TILEDATALAYER` folder but it's been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/removed-features) in 1709.

Is there really not a single way to do this?

Comment: Removing Cortana in its entirety is going to break Windows Search on Windows 10, that is a side effect, of disabling what now is a core component of Windows.  You won’t be able to avoid that issue.  If you truly want Cortana disabled, use Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe there's a way to hide the Icon instead?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the taskbar? You can hide the search/Cortana icon in the context menu, but the search still works when you type in the Start menu.

Answer (score 5):

If what you need is to disable Cortana, but keep the search behavior, as in LTSB/C, this can be accomplished either via Group Policy or the Registry (see [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-turn-off-cortana-windows-10)), resulting in the default local Search behavior (Cortana name & icon will still show in Start Menu).

- Cortana and Search are actually `SearchUI.exe` behaving as one or the other, depending on the configuration in Group Policy or the Registry
- The icon & name are not configured based on this; Product Policy and `Cortana-AllowCortana-Enabled` takes precedence with all these tweaks (`0` is Local Search, while  `1` is Cortana-enabled if not disabled in GP/registry). 
   `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions\ProductPolicy` is specific to Windows version installed, with `Cortana-AllowCortana-Enabled` set to `1` in Home/Pro/Ent and `0` in LTSB/C

  - Changing this to `0` will get the desired result, however that value is a kernel protected registry entry, and if modified in a normal session, it's silently discarded; it's only possible to modify it with some additional steps (see [here](https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/windows-product-policy-editor.39411/)), but once modified, the SPP service will kick in at some point and refresh everything back (disabling SPP is not recommended since that could break other things, such as activation).

The other way is a patch to `Cortana.BackgroundTask.dll` & `Cortana.Core.dll`, which are checking for that policy flag (what I used).

Once patched to always return false on the Cortana-enabled check, Search is back: [image]

Comment: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions\ProductPolicy` is a `REG_BINARY` value, not a key with a `Cortana-AllowCortana-Enabled` value. I don't understand what point this post is trying to make about it. Is there some specific byte in it that you need to modify bits of?

Comment: There is some information about it at https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/api/ex/slmem/productpolicy.htm - apparently it's used to store license information.

Comment: About the second link in the post (https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/windows-product-policy-editor.39411/) - you need to be a registered user to be able to view that post. I don't know if it was publicly accessible when this was posted, but it isn't now.

Comment: Okay... `Cortana-AllowCortana-Enabled` is an option in a tool called "ProductPolicyEditor" or "Windows Product Policy Editor" that you may be able to download from https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/windows-product-policy-editor.39411/ . I don't know if you can get the source, or if it just comes as a binary blob. I also don't know if any of the download links are still valid, or if I'd trust the tool or its creator.

Comment: Regarding the ProductPolicy Registry value, the same link tells us: *ProductPolicy is protected by kernel - if you write the value - its content remain unchanged although SetValue operation succeeds. To overcome this protection you need to reboot in setup mode*

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following in Powershell on Windows 10 v2004:

- To remove for current user:

  ```powershell
  Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.549981C3F5F10* | Remove-AppxPackage
  ```
- To remove for all users [admin terminal]:

  ```powershell
  Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *Microsoft.549981C3F5F10* | Remove-AppxPackage
  ```

Functionality can be added back from the store.

Answer (score 2):

Install latest `winget` from https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases, then run:

```
winget uninstall cortana
```

Note: this will uninstall not [just] disable